# SharePoint authentication in external page

Tags: authentication

We have a webapp, which is hosted on a normal IIS. Our client wants to host the webapp in a SharePoint page. This is how the page roughly looks:

```
<sharepoint site>
    <div>
        <iframe src="mypage.com" />
    </div>
</sharepoint site>
```

As authentication they want to use SharePoint authentication, which gives us a problem. We need to be able to authenticate against the SharePoint from an external site.

Is that possible?
If yes how do we build a working solution. If no, are there any other options to use at least the same authentication database like the SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single Page and want to keep SharePoint as the Authenticating source. The easiest option is to create a Page in SharePoint Web Application and then edit the source of the page to make it look like the Page you are targeting.

Comment: I don't quite understand, what you mean. The webapp we have is a normal ASP.net MVC 4.5 project, which also should run seperate from SharePoint and then use Windows Authentication.